# php class set properties

Tags: class, properties, set

I can't understand this code:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->s = new stdClass();
$obj->s->p = new stdClass();
$obj->s->p->v = 1;
$obj->p = $obj->s->p;

echo $obj->s->p->v; //Return 1, OK
echo $obj->p->v; //Return 1, OK

$obj->p->v = 2; //Set the new value

echo $obj->p->v; //Return 2, OK
echo $obj->s->p->v; //Return 2, why??? I didn't set it!
```

I tested this code without using stdClass (real class) and result is same.

Please explain to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this line

```
$obj->p = $obj->s->p;
```

It means you copied `$obj->s->p` address to `$obj->p` so they both point to same address in memory. So when you do something with `$obj->p`, its change also reflected in `$obj->s->p`.

Comment: I've never heard this before. It's only true if I copied object, isn't it? Could you show me some manuals about this rule?

Comment: PHP 5+ objects are passed by reference. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php